# DRF Filtering model by another model id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, filtering, django-urls

I have this models:

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        "Organization name", max_length=100, unique=True
    )
    description = models.TextField("Organization description")
    
    districts = models.ManyToManyField(
        "District",
        related_name="organizations",
        blank=True,
    )
    

class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("District name", max_length=100, unique=True)
```

And I need to filter organizations by district id, so url should be:

`organizations/<district_id>/`

What is the better way to do it?

Currently I have two solutions, first:

urls.py

```py
router.register("organizations", OrganizationViewSet, basename="organizations")
router.register(
    "organizations/(?P<district_id>\d+)",
    OrganizationViewSet,
    basename="organizations_by_district",
)
```

views.py

```py
class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        district = self.kwargs.get("district_id")
        if district:
            return Organization.objects.filter(districts__in=[district])
        return Organization.objects.all()
```

Second solution:

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path(r"organizations/<int:district_id>/",
                get_orgs_by_district, name="org_by_district"),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```py
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
def get_orgs_by_district(request, district_id):
    objs = Organization.objects.filter(districts__in=[district_id])
    data = OrganizationSerializer(objs, many=True).data
    return Response(data, status=200)
```

Both solutions work, but which is better? And maybe there is another solution that I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter is optional, I'd just use query parameters so you can have only one url for both cases:

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class OrganizationsList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Organization.objects.all()
        district = self.request.query_params.get('district_id')
        if district:
            queryset = queryset.filter(districts__in=[district])
        return queryset

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('organizations/', views.OrganizationsList.as_view(), name='organizations_list'),
    ...
]
```

You'd call your API as follows:

```py
{{base_url}}/organizations/  # Retrieve all organizations
{{base_url}}/organizations/?district_id=5  # Filter against district_id
```

More details in the official doc [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).